# Wordpress wp-admin infinite redirect loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having problems with a wordpress site to enter the admin area.

If I enter with: http://www.example.com/wp-admin/

I get an infinite redirect loop but if I enter with:

http://www.example.com/wp-admin/index.php

it works

Comment: Need more details. Did you recently change something? Are you running apache? Fresh install? Sounds like a server configuration issue where index.php isn't being picked up by default.

Comment: Yes... more details, have you by chance modified your .htaccess or functions.php file ?

Comment: Yes, we move site to root folder, in sub-folder its working fine and we are using apache

Comment: Have you changed site url and home url before moving the site?

Comment: No,I have not changed site url and home url

Comment: Try with http://www.example.com/wp-admin no "/" at the end

Answer (score 0):

As `/wp-admin/` have a infinite loop redirect but `/wp-admin/index.php` works we could solve it by adding

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/$ /wp-admin/index.php [R=302,L]
```

in the `.htaccess` before the WP-rules.

However, this is not the best solution, it works.